# Setting global variable value within functions & if statements

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm just beginning with JavaScript, but I've searched and read about the js variable scope, and can't figure this out.

I want to be able to set a variable value declared outside any function, within the functions which also contains if-statements. But yet it does not change the global variable. Example:

```
var counter = 0;
goNext();    

function goNext()
{   
    if(counter = 0)
    {
        counter = 3;
    }
}

alert('I now want counter to be 3! How?');
```

Comment: You are not doing a comparison `counter = 0` is assignment, use `===` instead of `=`

Comment: Indeed working, seems like I've got alot of reading to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the if you are assigning 0 to counter

```
if(counter = 0)
```

The code needs to be

```
if(counter == 0)
```

or

```
if(counter === 0)
```

Using a tool like [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) will hlp you find these errors. By pasting your code into the interface, it will show you warnings. When I paste your code into the page it produced:

```
One warning
6   Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.
```

Comment: I would recommend `===` as it's generally considered better practice. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript